# What options are available for the openssl -subj argument

Tags: openssl

I have found numerous posts online showing how I can use `openssl req ... -subj "/C=US..."` to generate a certificate in a non-interactive way.

What I can't find anywhere is documentation showing all the options available for the `-subj` argument. Is there somewhere I can find the different tokens and what them mean and what values are acceptable? For example, I would expect to find something like:

```
C for country with acceptable country codes of US=United States, CA=Canada, etc.
```

Comment: The subject is a *Distinguished Name (DN)*. Also see [RFC 4514, String Representation of Distinguished Names](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt). You can find the man page for the `openssl req` subcommand at [`openssl req(1)` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/req.html).

Answer (score 7):

Someone on the IRC channel ##openssl pointed out that these are a Distinguished Name, which led me to [Distinguished Names](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q009860_.htm). He pointed out that the full spec is [RFC 5280, Section 4.1.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4).

Comment: That first link is broken, but the edit queue is full so I can't update it. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=certificates-distinguished-names This seems to be working though.